# Macro retrieving from CMake

Tags: c, cmake, macros

I have the following code:

```
#if defined(__WIN32) || defined(__WIN64)
// Windows compiler compiles this code
#  define WINDOWS_PLATFORM
#elif defined(__linux__)
// GCC compiles
#  define LINUX_PLATFORM
#else
#  error "unsupported platform"
#endif
```

Is CMake able to check for the macros *WINDOWS_PLATFORM* or *LINUX_PLATFORM* and set the source file path accordingly to *win/* or *posix/* ?

Answer (score 3):

CMake has its own variables to check if you are on a particular platform. For example, using the following code you can check if you are on one of the most popular platforms and adjust whatever you need accordingly:

```
if(WIN32)
...
elseif(APPLE)
...
elseif(UNIX AND NOT APPLE AND NOT CYGWIN)
...
endif()
```

So you don't need any custom macros there — CMake has such a functional built-in.